# dispatch_async and unexpected non-void return value in void function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dispatch-async

I have a function in my `appDelegate` that returns user's current location.

Now I want to call it asynchronously at some other place and I did:

```
func handleLocation() -> CLLocation {
  let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.startGPS()
    while (!appDelegate.isLocationFixed()) {
      sleep(1)
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      return appDelegate.getLocation()
    }
  }
}
```

but now this line `return appDelegate.getLocation()` brings me the error:

> unexpected non-void return value in void function

I don't know too much about threads in `Swift` yet, could you help me with fixing this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
```

and

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
```

are actually creating closures/functions, so any code within them will relate to that function, not

```
func handleLocation() -> CLLocation {
```

If you're doing an asynchronous operation within a function, you can't really have a return statement after the asynchronous operation is completed. Instead, you should use a completion handler in your function. e.g.:

```
func aSyncFunction(completionHandler: (AnyObject) -> ()) {

    //do async opporation

    completionHandler("finished") // call the completion block when finished
}
```

Here's how I would implement it for your use case:

```
func handleLocation(completionBlock: (CLLocation?) -> ()) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                completionBlock(nil)
            }
            return
        }
        appDelegate.startGPS()
        while (!appDelegate.isLocationFixed()) {
            sleep(1)
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            completionBlock(appDelegate.getLocation())
        }
    }
}
```

example usage:

```
handleLocation { (location: CLLocation?) in
    if let location = location {
         //use valid location
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm so can I just put the body of my function inside of the aSyncFunction? Could you show me exactly how could I do it? I'm not sure if I'm getting the concept right here, thanks!

Comment: Added an example for your use case, let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just pasted it into my xcode and I'm getting error near this line: `handleLocation { (location: CLLocation?) in` saying that it expected declaration. Is that a typical error in this case?

Comment: Thanks :) The very last thing - I hope - is this error that I'm getting when I try to compile: http://i.imgur.com/Fbf97lG.png Have you seen it before?

Comment: forgot the return in the guard...I think I need more coffee. edited.